# How do I place my two tables side by side through CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.items {
  float: left;
}

.secondItem {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  float: right;
}

.page-header table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 80%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.tableBody {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div className="page">
  <Typography>
    <table className="items">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th className="header">items:</th>
        </tr>
        <th>
          Hi
        </th>
      </tbody>
      <tbody className="tableBody">
        {Items.map((item, i) => (
        <td key={item.id}>
          item:{item.id}
          <br />
        </td>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <Table className="secondItem">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>Second:</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>
            Item
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <tbody className="secondBody">
        <td>
          {seconds.map((second) => (
          <tr key={second.id}>
            {second.data.text}
          </tr>
          ))}
        </td>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
    <br />
  </Typography>
</div>
); };
```

I would like to place my two tables side by side but the second table is now placed below the first table instead. How do I style it so that the table is next to each other?

[image: Position of the table]

I have added my code and have tried many methods for CSS such as float:left, float: right, etc. I am currently a beginner and have no idea on how to style the table.

Comment: try using `flexbox` if you can (just add `display: flex;` to the parent container)

Comment: Thanks but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:inline-flex` to solve this problem

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.table {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table one">
    <table>...</table>
  </div>
  <div class="table two">
    <table>...</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This kinda helped me. But inside the first table, there are 2 divs and now they are side by side. I want the two tables to display side by side but the divs in each table to be displayed vertically. How do I do that?

Comment: Instead of using inline flex, I used inline-table! Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this would be to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Set `display: flex` on the parent component, together with a `flex-direction: row` property to explicitly set the `flex` items direction to horizontal.

Here's a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/o6rqsLfj/.

I would also highly suggest [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) guide for learning how flexbox works.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```